# Evaluating $\cot(\cos^{−1}(|\sin x|+|\cos x|)+\sin^{−1}(−|\cos x|−|\sin x|)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Let $g(x)=ax+b$, where $a<0$ and $g$ is defined from $[1,3]$ onto $[0,2] $.
>   Then the value of
>   $$\cot(\cos^{−1}(|\sin x|+|\cos x|)+\sin^{−1}(−|\cos x|−|\sin x|)$$
>   is equal to which of the following?
>
> - $g(1)$
> - $g(2)$
> - $g(3)$
> - $g(1)+g(3)$

---

The website Doubtnut presented [the following answer](https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/let-gxax-b-where-a-lt-0-and-g-is-defined-from-13-onto-02-then-the-value-of-cotcos-1sinx-cos-x-sin-1--41948255):

Consider 
$F(s) = \cot(\cos^{−1}(|\sin x|+|\cos x|) + \sin^{−1}(−|\cos x|−|\sin x|))$.

But $|\sin x|+|\cos x| \in [1, {\sqrt2}]\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

$\therefore F(x) = \cot(\cos^{−1}(1)+\sin^{−1}(−1)) = \cot(0−\pi/2) = 0 = g(3)$

(As $F(x)=0$, $\forall x\in D_F$)

---

> What is $D_F$ (in the end)?
>
> I guess that plugging in any permitted value of $|\sin x|+|\cos x|$ will give the answer, but is there a way to actually prove it will be the same for **every** value in the permitted range?

I realize that in an exam such as JEE such time-saving hacks are very helpful, but I would like to know if a formal solving process is possible. Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is correct. They only not explain why $ |sinx|+|cosx| \in  [1, \sqrt{2}] \forall x \in R$, but it isn't hard to figure it out.

First, let's $ S = |sinx|+|cosx| $, then:

$$ S^{2} = (|sinx|+|cosx|)^{2}  = 1 + |2sinxcosx| = 1 + |\sin2x| $$

Since $ 1 \leq 1 + |\sin2x| \leq 2 $, that means $ 1 \leq S^{2} \leq 2 $ or $ 1 \leq S \leq \sqrt{2} $

And in the final statement, it's $D_F$, which means domain of $F(x)$, not DF.

I think their proof you mentioned above is the best. The only thing is they do not explain clearly for their step.

Comment: I guess putting in any permitted value of S should give us the answer, but is there a better way to actually prove it?And what does the final statement("(As F(x)=0, ∀ x∈DF)") mean?

Comment: @KishoreKhanna It's $D_F$ (domain of F(x)), not DF. That final statement means $F(x) = 0, \forall x \in D_F$

Comment: thanks for clarifying that, but is there a way to **prove** that F(x) will be zero for any permitted value of S?

Comment: I think their proof you mentioned above is the best, the only thing is they do not explain clearly for their step.  
I also re-edit my answer for your question

Comment: But how did they conclude that F(x)=0 for **all** x in the domain?

Comment: @Keyenke Because of the fact that $ |sinx|+|cosx| \in  [1, \sqrt{2}], \forall x \in R$, and since $sin^{-1}$ and $cos^{-1}$ only accept $x \in  [-1, 1] $. Therefore, $|sinx|+|cosx| = 1, \forall x \in R$. And so, $F(x)=0$, for any x in its domain

Comment: Oh yes that definitely makes sense, thanks a lot.