# If $g(x) = ax+b$, where $a<0$ and g is defined from [1,3] to [0,2] then value of

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

If $g(x) = ax+b$, where $a<0$ and g is defined from [1,3] to [0,2] then value of 
$cot(cos^{-1}(|sinx|+|cosx|)+sin^{-1}(-|sinx|-|cosx|))$

I am not getting how to solve this can anyone help

options

- g(1)
- g(2)
- g(3)

Comment: The $x$ in $g(x)=ax+b$ is presumably a variable, not a fixed real number. What does the $x$ occurring in the trigonometric expression denote?

Comment: And what does $g$ have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The question is so bizarrely worded, that I suspect that the OP is (plausibly) simply reproducing the problem that was given to him.  Another example of brevity is the soul of bizarrely worded problems.  I suspect that the first step is to assume that $g(x)$ is a bijection from $[1,3]$ to $[0,2]$ and use that assumption to deduce the explicit values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Continuing previous comment, I suggest that you then manually evaluate each of the three options, $g(1), g(2),$ and $g(3)$.  Then choose **any** **convenient** value for $x$, evaluate the expression, and see whether it corresponds to one of $g(1), g(2), g(3).$  If so, I would **meta-cheat**, presume that in order for the problem to *make sense*, all values of $x$ would have to evaluate to the same option, and consider myself done.  You have the **option**, if you wish of trying to prove that any value of $x$ would so evaluate.

Comment: I already voted to close for other reason, but later realized there is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552827/evaluating-cot-cos%e2%88%921-sin-x-cos-x-sin%e2%88%921%e2%88%92-cos-x%e2%88%92-sin-x?rq=1).

Comment: @Ennary I seem to be mistake prone now.  I did click the link and I did read the question, but for some reason, I blind-spot ignored the cited question's reference to $g(x)$.  You are right, and I have deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range of $|sinx|+|cosx|$ is $[1,√2]$ and cos inverse and sin inverse can take input from [-1,1] implies that $|sinx|+|cosx|=1$
and in g(x) ,a<0 means it is decreasing function g(1)=2 and g(3)=0.
Now value of
cot(cos−1(|sinx|+|cosx|)+sin−1(−|sinx|−|cosx|)) comes 0 means g(3) is answer

Comment: If $g(3)$ is the answer, then what was the question?